# SwiftUI Strange animation behavior inside a TabView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I'm animating the progress of a bar (below), I have it embedded inside 2 parent views: parent 1 and parent 2.  Both parent views are tabs in a TabView.  When the app loads the animation in parent view 1 is as expected, but when tapping on the tab to navigate to parent view 2, the bar seems to fly in from the bottom left of the screen?

```
struct BarView: View {
    
    var progress: Double = 0.0
    
     var progressAnimation: Animation {
        Animation
            .linear
            .speed(0.5)
            .delay(0.5)
     }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                        .fill(Color(.lightGray))
                        .opacity(0.1)
                        .frame(height: 15)
                        .overlay(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
                        .fill(getColorForBar(progress: progress))
                        .frame(width: getFillWidth(progress: progress, geometry: geometry), height: 15)
                        .animation(self.progressAnimation)
                         }, alignment: .leading)
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Progress animation can be a let.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to link animation to value of progress state, like

```
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.0)
    .fill(getColorForBar(progress: progress))
    .frame(width: getFillWidth(progress: progress, geometry: geometry), height: 15)
    .animation(self.progressAnimation, value: progress)   // << here !!
     }, alignment: .leading)
```